# git grep <pattern> <stash> shows diff, but git stash show <stash> doesn't?

Tags: git, grep, diff

I'm currently trying to find some changes in a stash, which I know is `stash@{1}`. For this, I'm using `git grep`:

```
git grep somePattern stash@{1}
```

This returns me what I'm searching for.

However, when running `git stash show`, these changes aren't here and I get a different diff, not containing my changes.

```
git stash show stash@{1}
```

Same thing if I try to `git stash apply` said changes.

Is there any behavior of `git stash` that is preventing changes to be part of this stash when showing/applying it?

Answer (score 4):

`git grep` searches for a pattern in *the complete content* of a commit (not just the changes it introduced).

If `somePattern` is present in any other file (including a file not changed in the stash), you will see an output.

---

If you want to spot files where the *changes* contain the pattern, instead of `git grep`, try one of :

```
git show -S somePattern stash@{1}
# or :
git show -G somePattern stash@{1}
```

---

In your case : it looks like the pattern you are looking for is not part of the *changes* of `stash@{1}`.

If you want to inspect the content of all your stash entries, use one of the `-S` or `-G` options on `git reflog stash` :

```
# * you also need the '-m' option when inspecting the stash, because all
#   stash entries are actually merge commits
# * '-p' will print the patch of files matching the pattern, and will
#   allow you to see if those are the changes you are looking for
git reflog --oneline -m -S somePattern -p stash
```

Comment: Be careful with `git show` here: you'll need `-m` and/or `--first-parent`. (With an upcoming Git, there's a new flag that means `-m --first-parent`.)

Comment: Thank you for this. I've tried both commands, and they still didn't show the diff I was searching for.

Also, `somePattern` doesn't seem to be present in current commit state:
- If I `git grep somePattern stash@{1}`, it shows the file
- If I `cat path-of-file-from-that-grep-output`, the change is not there. So logically, it should be present in the `git show` or `git stash show` output?

Comment: @torek : I had forgotten a stash is a merge commit, updating my answer. Thanks. `[edit]` I need the `-m` option for `git reflog -S ...`, but `git show -S ...` works straight away (the diff is presented in the combined diff format by default). Is this behavior a recent change ?

Comment: You'll get a diff if the merged file is "different from all parents" (so, different from both index and previous-commit). I may have overstated the case in my own answer: if you haven't `git add`-ed a file, you can get a diff. Still, the combined diff will drop some changes from this diff. It's never been completely clear to me which diff hunks get dropped in combined diffs; I should take some time to study that...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible reasons for this:

- A *stash* is actually a complex of two (or sometimes three) commits.  The `git grep` operation looks in the `W` (work-tree) commit, completely ignoring the `I` (index-state) commit.<sup>1</sup>
- As [LeGEC notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826101/1256452), `git stash show` generates a diff.  The diff is from the `W` commit's parent to the `W` commit.
- It's easy to accidentally run `git show stash` instead of `git stash show`.  This *works*, for some definition of *work*, but also fails because a stash is a complex of commits.  The `W` commit has the form of a merge commit.<sup>2</sup>  This makes `git show` use a *combined diff* to show it, and because of the way stashes are built, this combined diff can be *completely empty* (it depends on what you've `git add`-ed when you run `git stash`).

It's hard to know precisely which of these issues you might have hit, but all of them will cause confusion.

---

<sup>1</sup>If a third commit exists, it holds the untracked files, and `git grep` ignores it too.  That's because `refs/stash`, or `stash@{whatever}`, points to the `W` commit.

<sup>2</sup>This means that the `W` commit *is* a merge commit.  But it wasn't made by `git merge`, and the normal Git tools, applied *to* it, produce nonsensical results.  The reason `W` is a merge is to be able to find the rest of the stash commits, plus the commit from which the stash was made, all with simple gitrevisions syntax.